# Can you explain this kind of tense usage?

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense, tense-agreement, future-time

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLA3Fiin0ro)

> Tear up the scroll and the beast **goes back** to the place it came from.

I heard it in an anime episode, refer to the video at 14:00. I thoughf it should be **will go back**. Explain, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are confident about what will happen in the future, we can use the present simple tense. In this case, the speaker is sure that if you tear up the scroll, the beast will certainly go back to the place it came from.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is not incorrect.

'**[Goes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goes)**' is in the present tense, where as '*will go*' is generally in future tense.

Now the question is, why is the sentence written in present tense?

**My Theory** *:

When it comes to games and animes, the user must be kept fully involved in the scenario. This may involve the usage of present tense, rather than how the sentence should naturally be constructed. In my opinion, if the animie had said:

> "Tear up the scroll and the beast **will go** back to the place it came from."

it would have had lesser impact on the viewer/ reader, when compared to

> "Tear up the scroll and the beast **goes** back to the place it came from."

If the scroll is ripped apart, and assuming that we have done it, the beast, leaves us alone and goes away.

The former lacks a certain punch than the latter. Then again, this is my opinion.

It may also show the immediacy of the events. As soon as the scrolls are ripped, the beast returns.

Let us split the sentence into two distinct events:

1. The scroll is torn.
2. The beast returns to wherever it came from.

In the sentence, the speaker is speaking as if the first event has already happened. In which case, we have to use the present tense, not that using '*will*' is wrong, but it's how the sentence is verbally delivered.

There are times when spoken English may vary when compared to written English. I can not come up with any such examples at present, but if I do, I'll edit this post. Having said that, this maybe an example of one such event.

(*) **NOTE** : This is not an answer I can back with facts and figures, atleast for now.

Comment: Why is the sentence incorrect? And **the beast, leaves** shouldn't have a comma.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, The sentence is **not** incorrect.

Comment: Why I am asking?

Comment: The sentence is not wrong. Both the sentences are correct. The original sentence - _"Tear up the scroll and the beast goes back to the place it came from."_ and you're version are both right.

Comment: Indeed it is, but I would be cautious of taking advice on English from someone who writes "you're version" instead of the correct "your version".

Comment: @alephzero, sorry, my bad. But then you shouldn't be so judgmental. People make mistakes. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out. Cheers.